# Find Marginal CDF probability from PDF (2 random variables)

Tags: self-study, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

Given the following PDF of continuous 2 random variables:

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
       y^2 & 0\le y\le x\le 1;\newline
       0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Graph showing the region of integration with x and y random variables:

[image: limit of 0<y<x<1]

Question is to find the marginal CDF $F_{Y}(y)$ and $P[Y > x]$

My attempt to find joint CDF: $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$
$$
\begin{alignedat}{0}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{x}y^2 dydx \newline
&=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}y^2 dy dx\newline
&=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{y^3}{3}\Bigg|_{0}^{x} dx=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{x^3}{3}dx\newline 
&=\frac{x^4}{12}\Bigg|_{0}^{x}=\frac{x^4}{12}
\end{alignedat}
$$

And then to find marginal CDF of: $F_{Y}(y)=F_{X,Y}(x,y)$

$$
F_{Y}(y)=F_{X,Y}(\infty,y)=
$$

But where do I go from there? What does setting x to $\infty$ even mean?

And the question to find $P[Y>X]$, shouldn't it be 0 since $0\leq y\leq x\leq 1$?

UPDATE 12/17/2022

Based on @Xi'an's tip,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}cy^2dydx=1\\
\text{ implies } c = 3\\
$$
The original PDF must have been:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
  3y^2 & 0\le y\le x\le1 \newline
   0   & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Find PDF between $0\le y\le x\le1$

$$
\begin{alignedat}{0}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{y}3y^2dy_0dx_0\\
&= y^3x
\end{alignedat}
$$
Therefore, the joint CDF is
$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0 & y\le0,x\le0,\\
y^3x & 0\le y\le x\le1,\\
1 & y\ge1, x\ge1.
\end{cases}
$$
How do I compute for other conditions, for example $y>=1, 0<=x<=1$
$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_0^x\int_1^\infty 3y^2 dydx\\
$$
y goes to infinity?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of reposting the same, you can edit your previous post.

Comment: And also please add the [tag:self-study] tag to tour post.

Comment: $\frac{x^4}{12}$ cannot be right: it is not $1$ when $x=1$

Comment: And indeed the joint pdf cannot be $y^2$ on $0 \le y \le x \le 1$ since $\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^x y^2 \, dy \, dx= \frac1{12} \not=1$

Comment: But even if the joint pdf was $12 y^2$, then the $x^4$ you would have found would be the marginal CDF for $x$ not $y$

Comment: Instead you would want  something like $P(Y\le z) = \int_{y=0}^{z} \int_{x=y}^1 12 y^2 \, dx \, dy = 4z^3-3z^4$ at least for $0 \le z \le 1$.  You would then have $P(Y>x)$ as the complement of this so $1-4x^3-3x^4$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.   Note that $P(Y>x)$ is not the same as $P(Y>X)$ as here $x$ is just a number not a random variable

Comment: The previous question was closed and there's no option to re-open it. I thought I deleted it but it didn't get deleted for some reason.

Comment: You can delete it if you want for this post seems to have shown efforts.

Comment: You are right, x^4/12 doesn't equal to 1 when x=1. I must have remembered the question wrong. It was from a recent quiz.

Comment: There is an option to reopen the previous question but it's  an option offered to the users of the site who have enough privilege to vote to reopen the question if it meets our standards (which occasionally happens via the original poster editing the question)

Comment: We have many questions just like this, so reading some of those threads will likely help you.  A few can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=marginal+cdf+%5Bself-study%5D).

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** The density $f_{X,Y}$ does not integrate to one (1). This error can be easily corrected and the proper multiplying constant $$c=1\Big/\iint y^2 \mathbb I_{0\le y\le x\le 1}\text dy\text dx$$ derived.

**Hint:** Writing
\begin{alignedat}{0}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{x} cy^2 \text dy\text dx
\end{alignedat}
is not correct, because the symbol $x$ takes two different meanings in this expression, namely upper bound value **and** integrand symbol. The upper bound $y$ is furthermore missing.

The correct entry is, for $x_0,y_0\ge 0$,
\begin{alignedat}{0}
F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)&=\int_{-\infty}^{x_0}\int_{-\infty}^{y_0} cy^2 \mathbb I_{0\le y\le x\le 1}\text dy\text dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{x_0\wedge 1}\left\{\int_{0}^{y_0\wedge x} cy^2 \text dy\right\}\text dx
\end{alignedat}
where $a\wedge b=\min\{a,b\}$. Once the computation of $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is correctly completed,
$$F_Y(y)=F_{X,Y}(1,y)$$
since $1$ is the maximal possible value of $X$.

**Note:** The same care must be taken when computing $P(Y>X)$ [if I assume there is a typo in the question about $P(Y>x)$].