# Find Marginal CDF probability from PDF (2 random variables)

Tags: self-study, random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Given the following PDF of continuous 2 random variables:

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
       y^2 & 0\le y\le x\le 1;\newline
       0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Graph showing the region of integration with x and y random variables:

[image: limit of 0<y<x<1]

Question is to find the marginal CDF $F_{Y}(y)$ and $P[Y > x]$

My attempt to find joint CDF: $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$
$$
\begin{alignedat}{0}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{x}y^2 dydx \newline
&=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x}y^2 dy dx\newline
&=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{y^3}{3}\Bigg|_{0}^{x} dx=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{x^3}{3}dx\newline 
&=\frac{x^4}{12}\Bigg|_{0}^{x}=\frac{x^4}{12}
\end{alignedat}
$$

And then to find marginal CDF of: $F_{Y}(y)=F_{X,Y}(x,y)$

$$
F_{Y}(y)=F_{X,Y}(\infty,y)=
$$

But where do I go from there? What does setting x to $\infty$ even mean?

And the question to find $P[Y>X]$, shouldn't it be 0 since $0\leq y\leq x\leq 1$?

Comment: You asked twice: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599103/find-marginal-cdf-probability-from-pdf-2-random-variables